# Can't upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10 due to libgl1-mesa-dri package

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies, 19.04

I tried to upgrade my dist from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. Turned out, I had some packages to upgrade:

```
libgl1-mesa-dri/bionic-security 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1]
libgl1-mesa-dri/bionic-security 19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2 i386 [upgradable from: 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1]
```

`dist-upgrade` didn't upgrade them, so I tried to do it manually and this happened:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tried to install it manually, but it threw this:

```
marek@marek-GA-990XA-UD3:~$ sudo apt install libsensors4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libsensors4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libsensors4:i386 libsensors-config

E: Package 'libsensors4' has no installation candidate
```

updated information:

```
grep "bionic" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list:# deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main # wyłączony podczas aktualizacji do bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list.distUpgrade:# deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main # wyłączony podczas aktualizacji do bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list.save:# deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main # wyłączony podczas aktualizacji do bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list:# deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ # wyłączony podczas aktualizacji do bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list.distUpgrade:# deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ # wyłączony podczas aktualizacji do bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list.save:# deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ # wyłączony podczas aktualizacji do bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:# deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main # wyłączony podczas aktualizacji do cosmic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list.distUpgrade:# deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main # wyłączony podczas aktualizacji do cosmic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list.save:# deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main # wyłączony podczas aktualizacji do cosmic
```

Also, I found this answer: 
[Cannot upgrade 19.04 to 19.10 because of held back packages: libsnmp30](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185227/cannot-upgrade-19-04-to-19-10-because-of-held-back-packages-libsnmp30)
and added this ppa repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

and it sorta worked, i.e. I was able to upgrade all packages etc. So my question is now: Should I clean this mess before I try to actually upgrade my system?

Comment: @Kulfy I updated my question providing information you asked for and some other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look upgrade notice of either of the package, you'll realize those packages are being offered by repositories of Bionic Beaver (18.04). But since you are using Disco Dingo (19.04), keeping repositories of other release can harm your system and sometimes breaks the operating system quite horribly. In this particular case, Bionic still has libsensors4 but Disco as well as Eoan Ermine (19.10) has libsensors5 which obviously would lead to dependency issues. You need to remove other release's repository to avoid dependency issues and upgrade to newer release. For that, first of all determine which file has those entries. For that, you can use [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/grep.1.html).

```
grep "bionic" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

And put a pound(`#`) in front of those lines to comment/disable those by editing the file using nano or vi, whichever editor you prefer.