# Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 failing due to "broken packages after upgrade: ubuntu-desktop"

Tags: 18.04, package-management, upgrade, 20.04, ppa

Attempting to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 using:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
```

This fails with the message:

> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
>
> This was likely caused by:  * Unofficial software packages not
> provided by Ubuntu Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge
> package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and  try the upgrade
> again.

Prior to this I get a notice that third-party sources are being disabled for the upgrade.

The contents of main.log is [Here](https://textuploader.com/1uqmn)

It says at the end:

> 2020-07-26 08:53:18,226 WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for
> upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
> 2020-07-26 08:53:28,026 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages
> after upgrade: ubuntu-desktop'

As a result, I have tried all of the broken packages solutions I could find, none of which have worked. Running synaptic package manager and filtering by broken finds no packages.

I have installed ppa-purge but without an idea of which packages to remove with it, I haven't actually used it.

Comment: That is what you will need to do: remove any non standard PPA's with ppa-purge, so the software and libraries these introduced are removed. In your log, many foreign PPA's are listed. To be honest, a clean install will by far be the fastest and the *cleanest* solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and was able to resolve it using this answer
https://askubuntu.com/a/646918/309267

Update: The above answer didn't help on my second computer but this one works great
https://askubuntu.com/a/1242078