# PPA hiccup or broken PPA? Kubuntu

Tags: package-management, updates, kubuntu, ppa

I have several issue and at the moment I assume a PPA is the case of it.

I have disable every PPA, except the PPA from Cononical (Main), no universe, multiverse and restricted and no additional one.

So I would now try to remove all of the packages(listed below) and replace them with the version in the main PPA. But i would really like to know why this is happening...

```
debhelper/now 13.2.1ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
fonts-opensymbol/now 2:102.11+LibO7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
libc++1-10/now 1:10.0.1~+rc4-1~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libc++abi1-10/now 1:10.0.1~+rc4-1~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libdebhelper-perl/now 13.2.1ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
libdrm-common/now 2.4.103+git2012091830.9a7afc~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
libdrm-intel1/now 2.4.103+git2012091830.9a7afc~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libdrm-intel1/now 2.4.103+git2012091830.9a7afc~oibaf~f i386  [Installiert,lokal]
libdrm-nouveau2/now 2.4.103+git2012091830.9a7afc~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libdrm-nouveau2/now 2.4.103+git2012091830.9a7afc~oibaf~f i386  [Installiert,lokal]
libdrm-radeon1/now 2.4.103+git2012091830.9a7afc~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libdrm-radeon1/now 2.4.103+git2012091830.9a7afc~oibaf~f i386  [Installiert,lokal]
libdrm2/now 2.4.103+git2012091830.9a7afc~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libdrm2/now 2.4.103+git2012091830.9a7afc~oibaf~f i386  [Installiert,lokal]
libjuh-java/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
libjurt-java/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
liblibreoffice-java/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
libreoffice-help-common/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
libreoffice-java-common/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
libreoffice-style-colibre/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
libreoffice-style-elementary/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
libreoffice-style-yaru/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
libridl-java/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
libuno-cppu3/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libuno-sal3/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libuno-salhelpergcc3-3/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
libunoil-java/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
libunoloader-java/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f all  [Installiert,lokal]
uno-libs-private/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
ure/now 1:7.0.2-0ubuntu1~oibaf~f amd64  [Installiert,lokal]
```

The current Problem is, that I can not normally boot into kubuntu. I have to use `nomodeset` and I can not boot kubuntu in text mode (tty1). This question I have ask separately, not sure if all of them are case by the same effect or just happening independendly....

Any Help or new inside is highly appreciated.

---

Edit
ppa-purge oibaf displaydriver and kisak-mesa and reinstalled most of the packages used in the kubuntu live system.

Now I can see a loading screen and than nothing again... but at least a positive change

Comment: Try my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1185290/631600, you may have a different or multiple PPAs from oibaf... You might know which ones you have added.

Comment: I changed to the Kisak PPA, because in the Oibaf PPA the i386 were missing for a while. Resulting that I could not use steam. All of this packages are not part of the  ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers, or at least the should not.

Comment: Whatever `ppa` from oibaf you had, try to add it again and remove it with `ppa-purge`.

Comment: A ppa-purge remove all packages installed from that source?

Comment: Yes. it will remove the ppa and remove or revert all packages changed by the ppa.

Comment: Okay i will clean my system and look if it get better, the ppa from oibaf was not the issue. But thanks for the advice it is really helpful. (I tried it manually before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pLumo Thank that is much easier with `ppa-purge` to change the PPA.

btw. The graphic driver issue was resolved by the lated update of AMDGPU (2012-12-17) from AMD website.